# Kubernete have no access from eks pod to rds mysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-rds, amazon-eks

I am trying set up eks with rds mysql. I used eksctl to setup the eks cluster and I did not change any default network configuration. eks and rds are using the same vpc. 
This is the result in a debugging pod

```
telnet xx.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Connected to xx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
J
8.0.16\#t'Ti1??]Gp^;&Aomysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host
/ # nslookup xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Server:     10.100.0.10
Address:    10.100.0.10:53

Non-authoritative answer:
xxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com canonical name = ec2-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Name:   ec2-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Address: 192.168.98.108

nc -vz 192.168.98.108 3306
192.168.98.108 (192.168.98.108:3306) open
```

I used service mesh Istio I created a mysql client pod in a sidecar not enabled namespace I get an error message like following
Mysql client pod

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL sever on xxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com.
```

[image]
 I am new to vpc. rds and vpc are using the same vpc. they are connected within the private network?

If it says connection refused in my grpc server log, eks grpc server try to connect 192.168.98.108 and that is the private ip of the ads Do I need other configuration in vpc?. Any ideas? cheers

Comment: Are you sure you have eke and rds in the same VPC?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just double check eks and rds using the same vpc

Comment: VPC was created automatically when I created eks cluster using eksctl. I did not change any of eks network configuration default values (eks security group eks, eks network acls) For my sql I add inbound rules 3306 0.0.0.0:0 for vpc security group.

Comment: Do you have some sidecar proxy like envoy? or service mesh like Istio configured? Sometimes these need some outbound configuration.

Comment: I thought when you create a rds it automatically creates a vpc as well

Comment: you have to enable vpc peering between the two vpc's

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I do use service mesh Istio. I am looking at sidecar proxy. but I tried a testing mysql client pod in a sidecar not enabled namespace it failed to connect to rds.

Comment: When I create rds I select the same vpc as the eks vpc to avoid vpc peering.  The strange thing is that I could even not access that rds through mysql bench. I can access another rds that using automatic generated vpc. I use netcat the ip shows on the log it is open. I use nslookup rds it gives me back the ip same as the ip in the log but also can find the rds: No answer

Comment: Anything from AWS support team?

Comment: @Stella when creating EKS VPC, did you set the private networks flag?

Answer (score 0):

I did had the same scenario (RDS in the same VPC as the EKS cluster). What I did is as following:

1. I've created a Cloudformation template with which I created my custom VPC, 8 subnetes(3 public, 3 private for EKS cluster and 2 private networks for RDS database), internet gateway, NAT Gateway, route tables and routes.
2. Using eksctl with cluster configuration yaml I created the cluster and the node group. The node group joined my cluster.
3. Using aws cli, I've created the db-subnet-group (containing the 2 private DB subnet) and I also started and RDS instance. Then I've set up some security group to allow traffic to DB just from the 3 private subnets)

As reference to create my custom cloudformation template I used the template created by eksctl when running the create command with the flag --node-private-networking.